# Modify multiple HTML files in multiple folders automatically

Tags: notepad++, html

Is there some way to modify multiple HTML files in multiple folders?

I want to apply a new HTML design template over an old HTML website. The website is quite big, and doing this manually will take me quite a long time.

Basically I want to keep `title` / `meta` tags / and `<body>` elements as those are, and replace the rest of the HTML elements.

I know about Notepad++ but I don't know how to set it up to give me the right output.

Comment: Implement external Style Sheets - then you can update the style sheet and all pages will reflect the change.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do this with Notepad++, but there are other tools you can use to do it.  Microsoft's Expression Web (in the Expression Studio suite) will let attach a [DWT](http://www.outfront.net/tutorials_02/fp_techniques/dwt-1.htm) (Dynamic Web Template) to as many files as you want.  Every time you change the DWT all files it is attached to will automatically be updated, then the content that is unique to each page can be edited in each page individually (called an editable region on the DWT).  Dreamweaver has a similar feature, but I have not used it.

If you are a student you can get Expression Studio 4 free from [dreamspark](https://www.dreamspark.com/default.aspx), otherwise you can buy it [here](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/pd/productid.216452000?wt.mc_id=pointitsem_us_expression_sitelinks&wt.term=expression%20web&wt.campaign=5+-+expression&wt.content=raxxuw0b&wt.source=google&wt.medium=cpc&wt.srch=1&cshift_ck=%7Bm_uid%7Dcsraxxuw0b).

Comment: You may want to consider using Master Pages in Expression Web instead of the DWT (unless you need _old_ Dreamweaver compatibility).  Your asp.net developers will love you for it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open all the files in Notepad++;
2. Then go to Search;
3. Find in Files;
4. Find what part of the code you wish to change.
5. Next go to Search;
6. Replace;
7. Add what the replacement code should be;
8. Then click on "Replace in all opened documents".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to check [Htmltransl](http://diegothediablo.site50.net/) (freeware):

> Htmltransl is an applications that takes as input various html files,
>   zipped for convenience in input.zip, translates all the files
>   according to what specified in dictionary.txt (matching patterns are
>   substituted) and zips the translated html files